# Using delegates and RxCocoa shows Argument of '#selector' refers to instance that is not exposed to Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to have this delete to be reactive with RxCcocoa and RxSwift using DelegateProxy. I am getting this error:

> Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method
>   'rangeSeekSlider(_:didChange:maxValue:)' that is not exposed to
>   Objective-C

The delegate I am converting from this library: https://github.com/WorldDownTown/RangeSeekSlider/blob/master/Sources/RangeSeekSliderDelegate.swift

```
import CoreGraphics

public protocol RangeSeekSliderDelegate: class {

/// Called when the RangeSeekSlider values are changed
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - slider: RangeSeekSlider
///   - minValue: minimum value
///   - maxValue: maximum value
func rangeSeekSlider(_ slider: RangeSeekSlider, didChange minValue: CGFloat, maxValue: CGFloat)

...
}
```

And here is the the delegate proxy

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RangeSeekSlider

final class RxRangeSeekSliderDelegateProxy:
DelegateProxy<RangeSeekSlider, RangeSeekSliderDelegate>,
RangeSeekSliderDelegate,
DelegateProxyType {

init(rangeSeekSlider: RangeSeekSlider) {
    super.init(parentObject: rangeSeekSlider, delegateProxy: RxRangeSeekSliderDelegateProxy.self)
}

static func registerKnownImplementations() {
    register { RxRangeSeekSliderDelegateProxy(rangeSeekSlider: $0) }
}

static func currentDelegate(for object: RangeSeekSlider) -> RangeSeekSliderDelegate? {
    return object.delegate
}

static func setCurrentDelegate(_ delegate: RangeSeekSliderDelegate?, to object: RangeSeekSlider) {
    object.delegate = delegate
}
}
```

The reactive extension of the slider, this is where I get the error:

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RangeSeekSlider


extension Reactive where Base: RangeSeekSlider {
var delegate: DelegateProxy<RangeSeekSlider, RangeSeekSliderDelegate> {
    return RxRangeSeekSliderDelegateProxy.proxy(for: base)
}

var didChange: Observable<(Bool, Bool)> {
    let source = delegate.methodInvoked(#selector(RangeSeekSliderDelegate.rangeSeekSlider(_:didChange:maxValue:)))
        .map{ (parameters) in
            return (parameters[0] as? Bool ?? false, parameters[1] as? Bool ?? false)
    }
    return source
}
```

}

Comment: When adding it: @ objc can only be used with members of classes, @ objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes

Comment: The protocol _itself_ needs to be exposed to Objective-C (`@objc public protocol RangeSeekSliderDelegate`).

Answer (score 3):

The protocol *itself* needs to be exposed to Objective-C.

Change

```
public protocol RangeSeekSliderDelegate: class {
```

to

```
@objc public protocol RangeSeekSliderDelegate {
```

Comment: Hey Matt, your question was flagged as low-qual. Add a code explanation maybe?

Comment: @vacawama I see what you did there. :))))